# How can get the width for each swiper-slide element

Tags: jquery, html, css, swiper.js

How can get the width for each swiper-slide element?

This is my code:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">First Box</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Second Box</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Third Box</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Forth Box</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        setWrapperSize: true,
        freeMode: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('.swiper-slide').each(function(){$(this).width();})`

Comment: @techLove Thank you but I think that this will give me as %, not px I am right?

Comment: @AhmedMohamed http://api.jquery.com/width/ "The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width() method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a mathematical calculation."

Comment: no, it is in px. see http://api.jquery.com/width/. There are also functions like innerWidth() & outerWidth().

Comment: @Ethilium Really thank you and techLove Thank you but your code to can add a specific width for each swiper-slide like this $('.swiper-slide').each(function(){$(this).width(150);}) but i want to get the width for each swiper-slide, I hope you understand me.

Comment: I try something like your code and it's working but I must choose a specific width i want to get the width for each swiper-slide.

Comment: Why don't simply assign id's to each swiper and use $('#swiper-1').width() ?

Comment: yes I can do this but this will be very default because I use swiper for many anther things and with different texts so sure each swiper-slide will have different size hope you understand me :)

Comment: Are you trying to auto-assign widths? What is goal with this code?

Comment: Yes I want to auto assign widths for each swiper-slide sure each swiper-slide have a different width and it's depending on the number of letters because that I told you it very defaults to assign id's to each swiper.

Comment: may be share some js code for better understanding. simple is that use .width() to get width and .width(150) to set width to 150px

Comment: @techLoe Without adding a specific width like this: width(150) and use width() only it does not add any width, Hope you understand me, To understand more I must add a specific width to make your code working.

Comment: $('#oneElement').width($('#someOtherElement').width())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Jquery's eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select each element individually. Here is a demo of what I think you are requesting:

```js
$('#changeWidth').on('click', function () {
  $('.swiper-slide').eq(0).width(65);
  $('.swiper-slide').eq(1).width(150);
  $('.swiper-slide').eq(2).width(250);
  $('.swiper-slide').eq(3).width(350);
  console.log( $('.swiper-slide').eq(0).width() );
  console.log( $('.swiper-slide').eq(1).width() );
  console.log( $('.swiper-slide').eq(2).width() );
  console.log( $('.swiper-slide').eq(3).width() );
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
  width: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">First Box</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Second Box</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Third Box</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Forth Box</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="changeWidth">
change width
</button>
```